# cucumber scenarios and rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'm almost finished building my first rails application and now I have to cover it with cucumber scenarios and rspec tests. My knowledge about testing is pretty weak, I have only written a couple of rspec tests for simple ruby programs, so any suggestions on where should I start learning about these two things and how they work together?

Comment: What materials have you already found on yourself?

Comment: The Cucumber book and the RSpec book are good resources.   BTW you should start by writing the tests, that's part of the whole idea of BDD.  It's similar to TDD but at a higher level..   Write the tests first, then write the code to make the tests pass.    If you are writing your code first, you are doing it backwards.